# TypeScript | Facing Error while trying to import a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, paytm

I am not used to using node js and typescript.

I tried importing Paytm dependency using the following code:
`npm install paytmchecksum`
or
by adding the below code in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "paytmchecksum": "^1.5.0"
    ...
}
```

Now, I am using firebase, typescript and node.js.
When I try importing, using

```
import PaytmChecksum from "../node_modules/PaytmChecksum";
import PaytmChecksum from "paytmchecksum";
```

or any other thing. There are just errors. I believe maybe because the dependency is to be used with javascript rather than typescript.

I get the following error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module '../node_modules/PaytmChecksum'. 'd:/firebase-functions/functions/node_modules/PaytmChecksum/PaytmChecksum.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

sometimes I get this,

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'paytmchecksum'. 'D:/firebase-functions/functions/node_modules/paytmchecksum/PaytmChecksum.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/paytmchecksum` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'paytmchecksum';`

What is the workaround for this problem?

Comment: `import PaytmChecksum from "paytmchecksum";`

Comment: You are right, there are no typings defined for https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Node_Checksum/blob/master/PaytmChecksum.js

Comment: Regardless, you don't want to import directly from the node_modules in the file system.

Comment: @kevintechie I have tried other methods as well like how chris said but that too doesn't work.

Comment: @CoreyAlix so is there any workaround of this problem.

Comment: Looking at the package code for paytmchecksum, I'd be tempted to just use Nodes's crypto module and roll my own and ditch the outdated dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to create your own type declarations file or use @ts-ignore on the line before the import.

If you create your own type.d.ts file, you will need to make sure that it is included the project in your tsconfig.json project file.

The type file can be as simple as one line (./mytypes/paytmchecksum.d.ts):

```
declare module 'paytmchecksum';
```

This simply gets rid of the implied any and makes it explicit. You won't get any intellisense or type checking, but it will fix the error. You could go the extra mile and create a full type-definition file. If you, do you should add it to the @types repository so others can use it.

Then just add include to your tsconfig.json file:

```
{ "include": [
  "mytypes/paytmchecksum.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have planned to use some other payment gateway platform since there is a lack of documentation on the fintech website. But will accept this as an answer.

Comment: HI @kevintechie
Thanks for solution, above mentioned approach solves the module not found but at run time I am getting below error 

{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateSignature')

Code:

    import {PaytmChecksum} from "paytmchecksum";
    const checksum = await PaytmChecksum
      .generateSignature(JSON.stringify(paytmParams.body), 
    stagingMerchantKey);

This code works with

    const PaytmChecksum = require(
     "./../../../node_modules/paytmchecksum/PaytmChecksum.js");