# Unhandled error in paytmchecksum.generateSignature

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, checksum, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm payment api gateway, during creating paytmchecksum i faced below issue:

Issue:Unhandled error in paytmchecksum.generateSignature

If i don't add below line in index.d.ts file

`declare module 'paytmchecksum';`

It fails in deploying to firebase cloud functions saying Could not find a declaration file for module 'paytmchecksum'

If I add above mentioned entry, it compiles well but it fails in run time with below error:

```
{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateSignature'
```

- for PaytmChecksum

previous issue background: [Type script node js - paytmchecksum undefined - generateSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438279/type-script-node-js-paytmchecksum-undefined-generatesignature)

Comment: Can you have look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to resolve the error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'paytmchecksum'
```

- Add `paytmchecksum` under dependencies in `package.json`
- Use `require` instead of `import` as below

  ```
  var paytm_checksum = require( paytm/paytmchecksum)
  ```
- Create your own type declarations file or use `@ts-ignore` on the line before the import.

  Check this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71320160/18265570), If you wish to create your own `type.d.ts file`
- Run the following command to install `paytmchecksum` properly.

  ```
  npm install paytmchecksum
  ```

Also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61709806/18265570)

Comment: I tried above solution, but I am getting below issue:

{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateSignature'

Basically PaytmChecksum is undefined ?

Comment: @rakeshkejriwal are you mentioning about `var paytm_checksum = require( paytm/paytmchecksum)`?

Comment: yes,

const PaytmChecksum = require("paytm/paytmchecksum");

Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'paytm/paytmchecksum'

Comment: @rakeshkejriwal have you tried other solutions that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: yes Roopa, I have tried above mentioned steps as it is , but yet the same issue.

Comment: please feel free to send working project in ts language , above mentioned stuff works in js but in ts files these don't work.

Comment: @Rakesh At this moment, I can only find this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBgujkNy_AI)